# Replacement to empty from ^ moves ^ matching to the new position

Tags: regex, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to remove the first `0` and the last `1` in the string `00211`, but instead of `021` I get `21`:

```cpp
String temp = "00211";
TRegEx RegExp;
temp = RegExp.Replace(temp, "^0|1$", "", (TRegExOptions)roNone);
ShowMessage(temp); // "21", but I expect "021"
```

A similar issue with the expression `^.` - instead of removing the first char only, it drops them all.

How can I fix this?  I'm using C++Builder 10.2.3 Tokyo.

---

Same code in Javascript works fine:

```js
console.log("00211".replace(/^0|1$/g, ""))
```

And in C++, if I use g++ and `std::regex`, [it works](https://ideone.com/BVJlLY):

```cpp
cout << regex_replace("00211", regex("^0|1$"), ""); // "021"
```

Comment: Try `RegExp.Replace(temp, "^0(.*)1$", "$1", (TRegExOptions)roNone);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, such wokraround is good only if regexp is not entered by user...

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: I guess people are missing the point that this question is about the behavior in C++ Builder.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for edits, but why did you removed snippet?

Comment: @Qwertiy a reflex action. Most people don't use snippets correctly, using them to post code that can't possibly run in a browser, so my first instinct is usually to remove snippets when I see them.  I've restored this one for you.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in System.RegularExpressions. Even `"000000000211"` is reduced to `"21"`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, yep - seems like when it removes char, it by some reason moves the start of the string to the new position.

Comment: If you replace it with a single space instead of the empty string and then trim the string, you'll get what you want. But that is only a workaround.